# In MABL UI automation whenever I tried to upload a single file it is showing multi file input not supported, what will be the issue?

Tags: ui-automation

I am exploring the trial of MABL app for UI automation while Exploring I am trying to upload a single file to the web app I am testing but when I click on submit MABL shows the error that multi file input not supported where I am trying to upload single file only.

Please help, Thanks in advance.